# CORS Issue with Cloudflare Proxy: "Invalid CORS request" when accessing via domain but not IP

Tags: spring-boot, cors, cloudflare

I'm facing a peculiar issue related to CORS when using Cloudflare as a proxy for my domain.

```js
const data = new URLSearchParams();
        data.append('content', contentValue);
        data.append('phoneme', phoneme);
        fetch("/edit", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: data
        }).then((resp) => {
            resp.json().then((res) => {
                if (res !== 200) {
                    alert(typeof res);
                }
            })
        })
```

```
Request URL:
https://****/edit
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
403
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:7890
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

***Response***

> Invalid CORS request

**Background**
I have a Spring Boot application that serves an API. I've configured CORS in my Spring Boot application to allow requests from any domain. Everything works perfectly when I access the server directly using its IP address. However, when I access the server via my domain (which is proxied through Cloudflare), I encounter a "Invalid CORS request" error for my fetch requests. Moreover, I've noticed that any POST fetch request executed under my domain results in a 403 error. Interestingly, executing the same POST requests from other domains works without any issues.

**Server Configuration**:
Here's a snippet of my Spring Boot CORS configuration:

```java
// ... (other code)
http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
// ... (other code)
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("https://*.*.*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

1. Checked the CORS configuration in my Spring Boot application.
2. Verified that the issue doesn't occur when accessing the server directly via its IP address.
3. Checked Cloudflare settings for any Page Rules, Workers, or other settings that might interfere with the requests.
4. Cleared browser cache and also tried in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution:
Go to Cloudflare dashboard - Origin Server, create Certificates and add it to springboot, and change the SSL/TLS encryption mode to full.